# MySQL Queries overlapping each other

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with MySQL Queries, there are a couple queries that seem to be overlapping each other. Basically, I have some PHP code (being called via a REST API) using MySQL with PDO that inserts a value into a table if it doesn't already exist. If it exists, then it updates the record instead. Pretty simple stuff, and it seems to be working 99% of the time. But on certain occasions the same record gets inserted twice (instead of being updated the second time).

I looked into the MySQL log and found that on rare occasions the script is somehow being run twice at the same time (causing overlapping queries). Notice how the process IDs 95587 and 95588 seem to be overlapping.

```
95587 Connect     @localhost on ****
95588 Connect     @localhost on ****
95587 Query       SET NAMES utf8
95588 Query       SET NAMES utf8
95588 Query       SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `data` = '89158268' LIMIT 1
95587 Query       SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `data` = '89158268' LIMIT 1
95588 Query       INSERT INTO `my_table` (`data`, `date_created`, `date_updated`) VALUES ('89158268', '2011-08-21 17:11:10 ', '2011-08-21 17:11:10 ')
95587 Query       INSERT INTO `my_table` (`data`, `date_created`, `date_updated`) VALUES ('89158268', '2011-08-21 17:11:10 ', '2011-08-21 17:11:10 ')
95588 Quit
95587 Query       SELECT * FROM `another_table`
95587 ... more queries
```

This is the order of the code:

1. SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `data` = '89158268' LIMIT 1
2. if record found, then update my_table
3. else if record not found, insert new record into my_table and then continue other queries

Can anyone think of a reason why these 2 mysql processes seem to be overlapping each other? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By overlapping, do you mean running at the same time? And what exactly is the actual issue that you're having?

Comment: If data is a primary key, consider using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Two process IDs indicates two different connections to the server, indicating two separate PHP script invocations, suggesting two separate HTTP requests.

Comment: It means that there are 2 connections being made. It seems that the problem isn't in why are there 2 processes, your problem is the wrong approach to the problem. Using UNIQUE constraint and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE would solve the issue with duplicate records. After you take care of duplication, you can proceed to researching why are there 2 connections being made instead of one. Since the info you provided isn't sufficient, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the table before the select:

```
LOCK TABLE my_table WRITE;
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `data` = '89158268' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`data`, `date_created`, `date_updated`);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This will avoid any other MySQL session from using the my_table table, and avoid this race condition.

Comment: Why lock if there are more elegant and safer solutions? One of them is ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as posted in comments.